# Limit number of posts on a custom category template - breaking pagination

Tags: categories, templates

The following code was mentioned from one of the commentors, however it is breaking the pagination. Any corrections please

```
 <?php 
    include(TEMPLATEPATH. '/includes/headline.php'); rewind_posts();
    if (have_posts()) 
    {
    echo '<div class="gridrow clear">';
    while (have_posts()) : the_post();
    global $post;
    $query_string;
    query_posts( $query_string .'&posts_per_page=5' );
    include(TEMPLATEPATH. '/includes/loop.php');
    $q = $wp_query->current_post;
    $maxq = tj_current_postnum();
    if($q < $maxq-1 && is_int(($q+1)/2)) echo '</div><div class="gridrow clear">';
    $postcount++;
    endwhile;
    echo '</div> <!--end .gridrow-->';
    } else { 
    include(TEMPLATEPATH. '/includes/not-found.php'); 
    } 
    if ( $wp_query->max_num_pages > 1 ) tj_pagenavi();?>
```

Comment: I tried changing the value of $maxq to 5 (to limit to only 5 posts) but it doesn't work. Any help on this please

Comment: Based on the recommendations, this is the modified code.. but it continues to break pagination.

Comment: Well, i've pretty much exhausted all the options. Came across this resource [link](http://www.xcellence-it.com/tips-tricks/975/fix-wordpress-pagination-problems-when-used-with-query_posts/) and also few of the additional tips mentioned at the end of the post.. but nothing seems to be fixing the pagination problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell Wordpress to get only 5 posts per page. The parameter to do this is posts_per_page. You should use query_posts() function before your have posts as in the following example.

```
<?php
   // your includes and stuff

   global $query_string;

   query_posts( $query_string . '&posts_per_page=5' );

   // now your have_posts
   if ( have_posts() ) {
       // list the posts
   } else {
       // not found msg here..
   }
?>
```

Comment: the simple `query_posts( 'posts_per_page=5' );` will cause problems with pagination; 
expand it to: `global $query_string; query_posts( $query_string .'&posts_per_page=5' );`

Comment: Thanks for your help so far. This is how my code looks now and nothing happens (Sorry, i'm not a php expert) any suggestions

`<?php 
   include(TEMPLATEPATH. '/includes/headline.php');
   global $query_string; 
   query_posts( $query_string .'&posts_per_page=5' );`
Rest of code follows

Comment: Ignore my previous message... This fixed.. Thanks Hameed and Michael

Comment: @Michael Thanks for the correction, made the corrections in above answer.

Comment: I just noticed that the above code does break the pagination.

Answer (score 1):

The code you have at the top of this page has a nested loop. Is that what you want?

The following code would normally go above the while loop for "the_post()"

```
$query_string;
query_posts( $query_string .'&posts_per_page=5' );
```

This may not be your issue, but I thought it may help.

Comment: Thanks Daniel.. but it still continues to break the pagination even after using the code mentioned above.. placed above the 'while (have_posts... function

Comment: Have you changed the number of posts per page in the WP UI? In Settings->Reading. And can we see a link to the site. And it is not clear to me what you mean when you say "pagination is broken". Is there no pagination, are you getting a 404 error, etc.?

Comment: Yes, 404 error beyond page 8 (404 starts from page 9 onwards). In Wp settings, the default is set to 10 posts, but it in particular category template the post is limited to 5.

Comment: How many posts do you have?

Comment: 104 posts in this particular category

Comment: Are you using pretty permalinks -> /%category%/%postname%/? One thing I do to troubleshoot pagination is to turn off pretty permalinks and use the default permalinks. This can narrow down what the problem is. (And it would help to have a link to the troubled site.)

Comment: Thanks for your help so far Daniel. I came up with a work around so I don't have to limit the posts.